# Callback function with named parameter not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I get the following error:

`Error: The argument type 'Future<void> Function({bool success})' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function({bool success})' because 'Future<void> Function({bool success})' is nullable and 'void Function({bool success})' isn't.`

when trying to use my callback.
I got this function:

```
static Future<void> showConfirmationModal({
    required BuildContext context,
    required void Function({bool success}) callback,
  }) async {
    // doing stuff
    callback(true);
}
```

And I invoke it like this:

```
OverlayModal.showConfirmationModal(
  context: context,
  callback: ({required bool success}) async {
    if (success) {
      // do stuff
    }
  },
);
```

It works if I don't name the success parameter and do it like
`required void Function(success) callback,` ...
and `callback: (bool success) async {}`

But because my linter told me I should use named parameters with bools I wanted to change it but since then running into this error.

What am I doing wrong? Why does it say, that my callback is nullable?

Comment: Did you copy-and-paste the error message you received?  If that's the actual error message, then the error in your code is not being reported correctly.  The error message *should* say: "The argument type 'Future<void> Function({required bool success})' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function({bool success})'". (That is, it should point out that one of them has a `required` parameter.) It's also weird that `{bool success}` is allowed at all instead of being `{required bool success}` or `{bool? success}`.

Comment: @jamesdlin yes I copy-and-pasted the message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you have it defined it as

```
static Future<void> showConfirmationModal({
    required BuildContext context,
    required void Function({bool success}) callback,
  }) async {
    // doing stuff
    callback(success: true);
}
```

you say that `callback` must allow for success to be optional. If you use a callback with a `required` clause it wouldn't work because imagine if the body of `showConfirmationModal` says this instead

```
static Future<void> showConfirmationModal({
    required BuildContext context,
    required void Function({bool success}) callback,
  }) async {
    // doing stuff
    callback();
}
```

It wouldn't work with what you call it with. So to solve would be to make it required in the parameter requirement so like

```
static Future<void> showConfirmationModal({
    required BuildContext context,
    required void Function({required bool success}) callback,
  }) async {
    // doing stuff
    callback(success: true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
static Future<void> showConfirmationModal({
    required BuildContext context,
    required void Function({bool success}) callback,
  }) async {
    // doing stuff
    callback(true);
}
```

you need to declare callback as a Future function as follows, also you need to await the callback(true) call:

```
static Future<void> showConfirmationModal({
    required BuildContext context,
    required Future<void> Function({bool success}) callback,
  }) async {
    // doing stuff
    await callback(true);
}
```

Comment: I already tried that. but this doesn't change a thing. It says then `'Future<void> Function({bool success})' is nullable and 'Future<void> Function({bool success})' isn't`